# Div ao abrir está sobrepondo outra div

Tags: php, css, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET["p"])) {

      echo $phpUtil->erro ("Produto inexistente!");

   } else {

      $imagemAdd = "<img src='../_img/add.png' style='height:40px;' />";

      $produto = $produtosDao->pesquisaProdutoId($_GET["p"]);

      if(!isset($_GET["p"]) || $produto == null) {

          echo $phpUtil->erro ("Produto inexistente!");

       } else {


        $categoria = $categoriasDao->pesquisaNomeCategoria($produto->getIdCategorias());

        $linkCategoria = "<a href='index.php?categoria=".$categoria['idCategorias']."'>".$categoria['nome']."</a>";


        echo "<div class='fotosProduto'>";
        require_once "_required/carousel.php";
        echo "</div>";


        echo '    
          <div class="detalhesProduto">
            Categoria: <strong>'.$linkCategoria.'</strong><br /><br />
            Produto: '.$produto->getNome().'<br />
            '.nl2br($produto->getDescricao()).' <br />  <br /><br />
            R$ '.$phpUtil->formataMoeda($produto->getPrecoUnitario()).' <br />          
            <div>
               Estimativa do valor do Frete:<br />
              <input type="text" class="typeTextPequeno" id="cep" pattern="[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}" placeholder="Digite o CEP" required /> <span class="verFrete">Calcular Frete</span>
               <div class="freteResultado" style="display:none;"></div> <br />
            </div><br /><br />
            <div class="comprar"></div><br />     
          </div>        
        ';

        if($produto->getEstoque()==0) {
            echo '<script>
                   $(".comprar").html("Produto Sem estoque no momento");
                  </script>';  
        } else {

            echo '<script>
                   $(".comprar").html("<a href=\"carrinho.php?acao=adicionar&idProduto='.$produto->getIdProdutos().'\"> '.$imagemAdd.'</a>");
                  </script>';
        }

        $semFoto = "<img src='../_img/semFoto.png' alt='Sem Foto' title='Sem Foto' />"; 

       }
    ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

E o JS

```
  $(".verFrete").click(function () {

    $(".freteResultado" ).css("display","none");

    if($("#cep").val() =='') {

        alert ('Preecnha o CEP');

        $("#cep").focus();

        return false;

    } else {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "_required/calculaFrete.php",
           data: {cep: $("#cep").val(), peso: '<?php echo $produto->getPeso(); ?>', precoUnitario: '<?php echo $produto->getPrecoUnitario(); ?>'},
           dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function(response){

             if(response["erro"]) {
                 $(".freteResultado").html(response["erro"]);
             } else {              
                 texto =  "Preco PAC :  R$ "+response["precoPac"].toFixed(2)+"<br />";
                 texto += "Preco Sedex: R$ "+response["precoSedex"].toFixed(2);

                 $(".freteResultado").html(texto);            
             }

             $(".freteResultado" ).show("slow", function() {});
      });
    }
  });
```

A ideia aqui é quando clicar no botão, é ativado o JS que fará o calculo do frete. Isto está sendo feito.

Mas assim que calcula o frete, é exibida uma `div` abaixo com os valores que empurra o botão para baixo. Porém, quando o botão desce, o correto seria empurrar o restante do site (base) junto. E não é o que ocorre: O botão está sobre pondo à base.

Como corrigir isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Magic for Baby</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!--  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
  <meta name="author" content="no-cache" />  
  <meta name="generator" content="Magic for Baby" />
  <meta name="description" content="Magic for Baby" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Confecção, Confecção Infantil, Infantís, Muriaé, Muriaé-MG, Acessórios,  Roupas de bebês,  Bodys,  Macacão  de bebê,  Récem nascido,  Babydools,  Pijamas, Camisas de super heróis,  Vestidos de bebês,  Kids,  Baby,  Bebê,  Linha noite,  Moda bebê,  Moda infantil, Mijão, Regata, Camisa, Blusa, Calça, Tapa-Fraldas"  />
  <meta name="url" content="http://www.magicforbaby.com.br" />
  <meta name="Audience" content="all" />
  <meta name="language" content="pt-BR" />
  <meta name="rating" content="general" />
  <meta name="robots" content="ALL, follow" />
  <meta name="googlebot" content="ALL" />
  <meta name="classification" content="Confecção, Têxtil"/>
  <meta name="distribution" content="global" />
  <meta http-equiv="reply-to" content="contato@magicforbaby.com.br" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../_img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_global/_css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_global/_css/loja.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_global/_css/menuLoja.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_global/_css/jquery.cycle2.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_global/_css/lightslider.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_global/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_global/_js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_global/_js/lightslider.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_global/_js/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_global/_js/mascaras.js"></script> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../_global/_js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <!--[endif]-->
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            $(".tudo").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".carregando").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="carregando"><img src="../_img/carregando.gif"><br>Carregando...</div>

    <div class="entrada">
      <div class="sessoes"><div class="home">
  <a href="../index.php">
    <img src="../_img/home.png" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="busca">
  <form action="?busca" method="post" id="busca">
    <input class="typeTextMedio" required placeholder="Código ou Nome do Produto" type="text" name="busca"><input class="btnPesquisa" type="submit" value="Buscar">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="conta">

     <a href="painel.php">Minha Conta</a> || <a href="login.php?acao=logout">Sair</a>
</div>

<div class="carrinho"></div></div>
    </div> 

    <div class="topo">
      <div class="sessoes">
        <div class="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="../_img/logo.png" /></a></div>
        <div class="banner"><div class="cycle-slideshow slide" 
    data-cycle-fx=fadeout
    data-cycle-timeout=5000
    data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
    data-cycle-slides="div.slide">
    <!-- prev/next links -->
    <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
    <div class="cycle-next"></div>
    <div class="cycle-pager"></div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href='index.php?lancamentos'>
           <img style="width:890px;height: 117px;" src="../_img/_banner/_loja/lancamentos.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href='index.php?oportunidade'>
           <img style="width:890px;height: 117px;" src="../_img/_banner/_loja/oportunidades.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href='index.php?freteGratis'>
           <img style="width:890px;height: 117px;" src="../_img/_banner/_loja/fretegratis.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>

</div></div>    
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="conteudo">   
      <div class="sessoes">      
         <div class="menu"><ul class='menuPrincipal'><li>
             <a href='index.php?categoria=10'>
                  <img src='../_img/semFoto.png' style='height:30px' alt='Sem Foto' title='Sem Foto'> Body   
             </a>
         </li><li>
             <a href='index.php?categoria=11'>
                  <img src='../_img/semFoto.png' style='height:30px' alt='Sem Foto' title='Sem Foto'> Mijão   
             </a>
         </li></ul></div>    
         <div class="meio"><div class='fotosProduto'><script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vertical').lightSlider({
      gallery:true,
      item:1,
      vertical:true,
      verticalHeight:295,
      vThumbWidth:50,
      thumbItem:8,
      thumbMargin:4,
      slideMargin:0
    });  
  });
</script>
<h1 class='h1CentralisadoAvisos'>Produto sem fotos cadastradas ainda</h1></div>   
          <div class="detalhesProduto">
            Categoria: <strong><a href='index.php?categoria=10'>Body</a></strong><br /><br />
            Produto: Body P<br />
            Body em tecido... <br />    <br /><br />
            R$ 32,00 <br />         
            <div>
               Estimativa do valor do Frete:<br />
              <input type="text" class="typeTextPequeno" id="cep" pattern="[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}" placeholder="Digite o CEP" required /> <span class="verFrete">Calcular Frete</span>
               <div class="freteResultado" style="display:none;"></div> <br />
            </div><br /><br />
            <div class="comprar"></div><br />     
          </div>        
        <script>
                   $(".comprar").html("<a href=\"carrinho.php?acao=adicionar&idProduto=25\"> <img src='../_img/add.png' style='height:40px;' /></a>");
                  </script>  

    <script>
      $(".verFrete").click(function () {

        $(".freteResultado" ).css("display","none");

        if($("#cep").val() =='') {

            alert ('Preecnha o CEP');

            $("#cep").focus();

            return false;

        } else {

          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "_required/calculaFrete.php",
               data: {cep: $("#cep").val(), peso: '0.11', precoUnitario: '32.00'},
               dataType: 'json'
              }).done(function(response){

                 if(response["erro"]) {
                     $(".freteResultado").html(response["erro"]);
                 } else {              
                     texto =  "Preco PAC :  R$ "+response["precoPac"].toFixed(2)+"<br />";
                     texto += "Preco Sedex: R$ "+response["precoSedex"].toFixed(2);

                     $(".freteResultado").html(texto);            
                 }

                 $(".freteResultado" ).show("slow", function() {});
          });
        }
      });
    </script></div>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="base">
      <div class="sessoes"><div class="baseEsquerda">
  <label style="font-weight:bold; color: #fff; font-size:15px;">Mapa do Site</label><br />

  <ul class="menuBase">
    <li><a href="index.php" title="Principal">Principal</a></li>
    <li><a href="carrinho.php" title="Carrinho">Carrinho</a></li>
    <li><a href="contato.php?form" title="Contato">Fale Conosco</a></li>
    <li><a href="?freteGratis" title="Frete Grátis">Frete Grátis</a></li>
    <li><a href="?lancamentos" title="Lançamentos">Lançamentos</a></li>
    <li><a href="?oportunidades" title="Oportunidades">Oportunidades</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="barraBase"><hr class="hr" /></div>

<div class="baseDireita">

    <label style="font-weight:bold; color:#FFF; font-size:15px;">Magic for Baby</label> <br />
  Rua Sebastião José Rodrigues, 195<br />
  Telefones:   3721 4603, 9 8888 4603<br />
</div>

<script>$(".carrinho").append("<div class='carrinhoMais'><a href='carrinho.php'>CARRINHO</a> R$<label class='totalCarrinho'>127,87</label></div>");</script></div>
    </div> 

    <div class="final">
      <div class="sessoes"><div class="finalEsquerda">Copyright© 2016 Magic for Baby. Todos os direitos reservados.</div>

<div class="finalDireita">Desenvolvido por   :<a href="mailto:carcleo@bol.com.br?subject=Contato"><img align="right" class="imgFinal" src="../_img/carcleo.png" height="35" /></a></div></div>
    </div> 

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema esta no html, tenta colocar isso abaixo do botão: <div style="clear: both"></div>

Comment: Se não funcionar, coloca ai também o html para analisarmos..

Comment: já tinha tentado isso. E esse é todo o conteúdo. Mas se achar interessante, posso renderizar no browser e postar tudo, conteudo, base...

Comment: faça isso, por favor

Comment: coloquei lá na final da pergunta

Comment: Não consegui testar porque faltam seus arquivos css e javascript externos, se você não tiver uma domínio na web onde eu possa testar, me passa esses arquivos externos, por favor.

Comment: posso até fazer um zip com os arquivos mas não vai resolver pois tem muito calculo de frete feito em php (classe calculaFrete.php)

Comment: Não tem problema, só preciso do layout mesmo

Comment: www.hotplateprensas.com.br/aa.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div .detalhesProduto está com height fixado em 300px, troca essa propriedade para min-height: 300px.

Comment: era isso mesmo. obrigado